# IPP v3 Invoice QueryService not working with Skip/Take when using non-default fields

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

I'm trying to query invoices using the .NET IPP DevKit v3.

Following all the directions found on the documentation site, I can query invoices and add skip/take/order by/where/etc to the query when using ONLY default fields.  But, as soon as I add non-default fields, skip/take/order by/where/etc does NOT seem to work.

Here's the error:

```
System.ArgumentException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147024809
  Message=Expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[<>f__AnonymousType0`3[Intuit.Ipp.Data.Invoice,Intuit.Ipp.Data.Line[],Intuit.Ipp.Data.LinkedTxn[]]]' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[<>f__AnonymousType0`3[Intuit.Ipp.Data.Invoice,Intuit.Ipp.Data.Line[],Intuit.Ipp.Data.LinkedTxn[]]]' of method 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[<>f__AnonymousType0`3[Intuit.Ipp.Data.Invoice,Intuit.Ipp.Data.Line[],Intuit.Ipp.Data.LinkedTxn[]]] Skip[<>f__AnonymousType0`3](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[<>f__AnonymousType0`3[Intuit.Ipp.Data.Invoice,Intuit.Ipp.Data.Line[],Intuit.Ipp.Data.LinkedTxn[]]], Int32)'
  Source=System.Core
```

What am I missing here?

Code:

```
string AppToken = "your AppToken goes here";
string AppConsumerKey = "your AppConsumerKey goes here";
string AppConsumerKeySecret = "your AppConsumerKeySecret goes here";
string AccessToken = "your AccessToken goes here";
string AccessTokenSecret = "your AccessTokenSecret goes here";
string RealmCompanyId = "your RealmId goes here";

OAuthRequestValidator oauthValidator = new OAuthRequestValidator(AccessToken, AccessTokenSecret, AppConsumerKey, AppConsumerKeySecret);
ServiceContext context = new ServiceContext(AppToken, RealmCompanyId, IntuitServicesType.QBD, oauthValidator);
QueryService<Intuit.Ipp.Data.Invoice> qs = new QueryService<Intuit.Ipp.Data.Invoice>(context);

// This works...
var defaultQuery = qs.Select(c => c).Skip(0).Take(10).OrderBy(c => c.Id);
var defaultList = defaultQuery.ToList();

// This works...
var nonDefaultQuery = qs.Select(c => new { c, c.Line, c.LinkedTxn });
var nonDefaultList = nonDefaultQuery.ToList();

// This does NOT work!!
var nonDefaultQueryWithSkip = qs.Select(c => new { c, c.Line, c.LinkedTxn }).Skip(0).Take(10);
var nonDefaultListWithSkip = nonDefaultQueryWithSkip.ToList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This now works in the latest version (IppDotNetSdkForQuickBooksApiV3.2.0.0)

Here's an example:

```
QueryService<Intuit.Ipp.Data.Invoice> qs = new QueryService<Intuit.Ipp.Data.Invoice>(context);

string query = string.Format("SELECT *, Line.* FROM Invoice ORDERBY Id STARTPOSITION {0} MAXRESULTS {1}", startPos, pageSize);

var recs = qs.ExecuteIdsQuery(query);

foreach (Intuit.Ipp.Data.Invoice rec in recs)
{
    // do stuff...
}
```

.

Answer (score 1):

I tried on the API explorer-

```
Select *,Line.*, LinkedTxn.* FROM Invoice startPosition 1  maxResults 10 (which is your last query) and it works fine but not from .net sdk. I will double check this on the .net SDK and get back to you. Can you verify that you get the correct results on API explorer from this query?
```

Comment: I'm actually using a different test company than the one I have available in the API explorer, so I'm not able to reproduce those results there. Sorry